# how to show certain records in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 columns like so.

I want the result to be dog 6 only in PHP programming language. the following code gives me both as each grouped and i want dog only to appear in a page dynamically when the browser visit the page not by typing it this way "WHERE word = 'dog' " in the php mysql code.

```
<?php
$res=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT DISTINCT word, SUM(amount) as sum FROM action WHERE clients_id=".$_SESSION['id']." GROUP BY word");
?>
```

[image: I want the result to be dog 6 only in PHP programming language]

Comment: What have you tried? How does your data structure look like in SQL?

Comment: $res=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT DISTINCT word, SUM(amount) as sum FROM action WHERE clients_id=".$_SESSION['id']." GROUP BY word");

Comment: Okay, and what happens with this code vs. what should happen?

Comment: this code gives me another group result than what i want

Comment: Please add what it gives you and what you want. Also please show how/what `clients_id` is.

Comment: i add what it gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to learn to use parameters.

Second, I think your query should be doing what you want -- although inelegantly -- so my suspicion is that the two "dogs" are not the same.

The most common problem would be trailing or leading spaces.  Try this:

```
SELECT trim(a.word) as word, SUM(a.amount) as sum
FROM action a
WHERE a.clients_id = ?
GROUP BY trim(a.word);
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the client id parameter.

There can be other issues with two words that look similar, so this might not fix the problem.